# Art registry site: isn't this just a centralized DB?

Tags: database

Just trying to wrap my head around the claims here:: https://www.artory.com/how-it-works/

Essentially they work with an industry partner (auction houses like Christie's), use all of the information related to a sale that is signed by the partner (seller) and time-stamped to create a hash. Artory then sends a no value transaction to themselves (no token is created or ether transferred, just the gas to record the hash), with the idea that record could be shared by the buyer with other potential buyers to prove ownership without revealing identity through their web interface.

Here's an example: 
https://registry.artory.com/records/CHR-27R2E4D3/

Transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x240a6e1ccf87146dc22a60b95cd4a207436044177ec38b5713a5ca6df266ac72

And here's how they describe the process: https://registry.artory.com/records/CHR-27R2E4D3/validate-record/

Setting aside the complexity/impossibility of tying these digital records to the actual things they represent, I'm really struggling with why this is anything more than a completely centralized process that could be more easily and cheaply accomplished with a traditional database (aside from the marketing they get from tying it to blockchain). There is no token, sellers and buyers are completely disintermediated from the blockchain transaction, and from what I can tell the only way to interact with the information written in the transaction is through their website (it's not open source, the hash is encrypted, so if their website is shut down there's no way to know what the hash written to the blockchain represents).

Am I missing something?